# I am making a tic tac toe game in pygame and I want an image to be drawn on the screen when the mouse is clicked

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a tic tac toe game. When a person clicks in a box the x image is supposed to blit onto the screen. I tried it using pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP. I am able to blit the image onto the screen when mouse is left clicked. The problem is that even if the mouse moves a bit, the image disappears. here's the code:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 250 < mouse_pos[0] < 300 and 250 > mouse_pos[1] > 199:
    x2.draw()
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and 250 < mouse_pos[0] < 300 and 250 > mouse_pos[1] > 199:
    x2.draw()
```

Comment: Why do you need a `mousebuttonup` condition too? Wouldn't your logic work with just a mouse click?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to set 'states' for `x2`.

```
enable_x2 = False
...
while Running:
    ...
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 250 < mouse_pos[0] < 300 and 250 > mouse_pos[1] > 199:
            enable_x2 = True

    ...
    if enable_x2:
        x2.draw()
```

And you can set a state for every cell / image like so.

Comment: it worked. Thx a lot :)